# pigeonhole principle proof for division by $20$

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle

Given  $7$ integers such that no two have the same remainder on division by $20$, prove that we can choose  $4$ of those $7$ numbers, $\{a,b,c, d \}$, such that $a+b-c-d$ is divisible by $20$.

Comment: I edited your question, please check to make sure that I kept your meaning intact.

Comment: @lulu thank you so much, do you know why i have a -1 score ?

Comment: @sajjaddehghani Because this forum is not meant to do your homework ;)
Provide some context and show us what you have tried so far. (Looking at the questions your recently asked on the same subject :p (I didn't downvote however, but I could well do it :p))

Comment: I don't know, but it's possible that someone felt you should show more effort.  The problem feels a bit like a homework question and people here don't mind helping with that, but don't want to do your work for you.

Comment: @Zubzub I'm so sorry , but I have think on it and 3 other questions for 6 hours.

Comment: Sometimes when one is "stuck" on a problem, it helps to try a simplified version of the problem.  For example, what would be a good analogy involving division by three instead of twenty?

Comment: @hardmath thank you for your advice, I will do it in my future problems. thank you so much .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How many different pairs of integers can you make from 7 integers (Where we count (m,n) as being the same as (n,m)) ?

Can you show that, from these pairs of integers, at least 2 pairs (call them (a,b) and (c,d)) have the same sum modulo 20 ?

What does that tell you about a+b-c-d ?

Comment: this means that I can choose C(7,2) = 21 pairs and I have 21 reminder on division by 20, so with pigeonhole-principle I will have 2 numbers that are the same and a+b-c-d is divisible by 20. it was nice solution